# Why the WP Core team does not allow filter_* functions?

Tags: validation, sanitization, coding-standards

This question is somehow related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533122/when-does-filter-input-remove-slashes-of-post-variables).

Provided that is seems we have a solution for the magic quotes issues, why the WP Core team does not allow them?

This is unclear to me and I couldn't find any official statement explaining this decision: just mentions sparse in some trac tickets and blog posts:

- Apparently the issue has been rones by [@westonruter](https://github.com/westonruter): https://github.com/wp-stream/stream/issues/257
- This post from @westonruter actually looks like to be positive: https://weston.ruter.net/2013/10/22/revelations-about-filter_input/

As far as I can see, filter_* functions are the best way (even better than [WP core functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Input_Validation), in my opinion) to handle validation, filtering and sanitation.
Also, they are part of PHPNG (therefore, PHP 7) and everywhere I can see posts saying to use these functions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665813/should-i-use-php-superglobals-or-filter-input-to-retrieve-get-data) in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767894/warning-do-not-access-superglobal-post-array-directly-on-netbeans-7-4-for-ph), as well as [elsewhere](http://www.phparch.com/2010/07/never-use-_get-again/)).

Comment: Why not to simply ask nacin or other wordpress core people?

Comment: @MarkKaplun How would one even go about contacting people working on core or find a list of those people?

Comment: IIRC there is a  list of core contributors and leed developers for each version. most of them have blogs or are active on twitter, so you don't even have to go on the wordpress "IRC" or mailing list for that.

Comment: Just use it in your theme, plugin, whatever. You shouldn't care too much about what the opinion on core is when you only develop third party solutions. I use `filter_var()`, `filter_var_array()` and `filter_input()` all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because on the minimum version required it isn't always available since the SPL can be disabled on PHP 5.2 and below. The majority of installs running WordPress have it, but not all, and it's the same reason autoloaders and Iterators aren't used.

Moving to v5.3 as a minimum PHP would fix this however as the SPL cannot be disabled in 5.3+, but until that happens..

Comment: And even then I would guess it is unlikely to be used in core. If it is not broken there is no need to fix it.

Comment: My concerns were not really about why I must WP APIs in places of PHP functions, but for a clear reason why they refuse to use it. I've checked quite deeply, and the only missing information from me was that SPL can be disabled before 5.3.0.
Now this is the only possible reason for me, which applies, since WP minimum requirement is PHP 5.2.4. In my case I think I can live with the "risk" of asking user to have it enabled.